# AppendLine is not inserting new line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stringbuilder

I have the following:

```
StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();

if(IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{
errors.AppendLine("Enter value");
}

if(IsNullOrEmpty(value2))
{
errors.AppendLine("Enter value 2");
}
```

I would expect this to display:

`Enter value`
`Enter value 2`

But it is displaying:

`Enter value Enter value 2`

I have also tried:  `AppendFormat("Enter value{0}",Environment.NewLine);`

as well as with the `\n` character.

The errors string is outputted to an asp:Label like:

```
lblErrors.Text = errors.ToString();
```

Comment: Where are you outputting the text to? Some things will not respect the new line character (such as a single-line textbox).

Comment: It is an asp.net web form. The text is outputted to an asp.net label.

Comment: HTML do not show new lines. `<br />` do. So you gotto replace them.

Comment: Extraneous white space is ignored by HTML rendering engines.  You would need to output a "<br>" or some such.  Or emit your text into a "<pre>".

Comment: I never knew this, thanks.  Who ever down-voted? Care to explain why?

Comment: @Xaisoft: I didn't downvote, but the question was ludicrously ambiguous before Claudio edited it to include the asp.net tag. "It is displaying" is hardly clear - you could have been talking about a console app, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET, Windows Phone 7... anything. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet , sorry, I was thinking about putting the asp.net tag, but thought it might have nothing to do with it and I was just making some sort of syntax error.  I wouldn't go as far as saying it was ludicrous though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in some of the comments, HTML does not respect the new line character `\n`. You need to use `<br/>` instead.

Comment: Thanks again, by the way, would you happen to know how I would preserve the tab character as well?

Comment: @Xaisoft see my answer. It will preserve tabs as well.

Comment: antisanity's answer is probably best if you need all of this functionality. To my knowledge there isn't an escape sequence for tab. Usually I see it as `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`. Though some older browsers may condense this into a single space.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to preserve all formatting (including tabs, consecutive white-space, etc), you can apply the [white-space:pre](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop) style to your label or use an [html pre element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/pre).

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rTdxA/)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do something like

```
if(value.Empty == null){
   errors.AppendLine("Enter Value");
}
```

By the code you are showing it seems like it doesn't go into the if statement.

Comment: It is, but it is an asp.net web form and as other's pointed out, new lines are ignored by html.

Answer (score 0):

in to string u can make as well `errors.Append(Enviroment.NewLine);`

@Brian in c# new line isn't "\n" "\r\n" is correct syntax of new line character:)

Comment: `\n` is newline. `\r` is carriage return. Typically you see it as `\r\n` [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)